# Why is RX not running handler on a new thread?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I am using RX 2.2.5

In the sample below, I expect the handler (the delegate to `Subscribe()`) to run on a new thread however when running the app all of the 10 numbers are consumed on the same thread one after another.

```
Console.WriteLine("Main Thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

var source = Observable.Range(1, 10, TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
    .ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
    .Subscribe(n =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Value: {0} Thread: {1} IsPool: {2}", 
            n, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);
    });
```

Output:

```
Main Thread: 1
Value: 1  on Thread: 4 IsPool: False
Value: 2  on Thread: 4 IsPool: False
Value: 3  on Thread: 4 IsPool: False
Value: 4  on Thread: 4 IsPool: False
Value: 5  on Thread: 4 IsPool: False
Value: 6  on Thread: 4 IsPool: False
Value: 7  on Thread: 4 IsPool: False
Value: 8  on Thread: 4 IsPool: False
Value: 9  on Thread: 4 IsPool: False
Value: 10 on Thread: 4 IsPool: False
```

The fact that they run sequentially is a mystery as well since I am using the `TaskPoolScheduler` to generate the numbers.

Even if I replace the `NewThreadScheduler` with `TaskPoolScheduler` or `ThreadPoolScheduler` I still get one thread and the more interesting part is that in both those cases the `Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread` is `False`.

I cannot explain this behaviour as when I look at the `ThreadPoolScheduler` I see:

```
public override IDisposable Schedule<TState>(TState state, Func<IScheduler, TState, IDisposable> action)
{
  if (action == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
  SingleAssignmentDisposable d = new SingleAssignmentDisposable();
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((WaitCallback) (_ =>
  {
    if (d.IsDisposed)
      return;
    d.Disposable = action((IScheduler) this, state);
  }), (object) null);
  return (IDisposable) d;
}
```

I can clearly see `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem...` so why `IsPool == False`?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Basically, `ObserveOn` does not work the way you think and introducing a `Scheduler` to an operator tells the operator where the concurrency should happen. Also in Rx notifications are always serialized. Let's wait for one of the experts to write a definitive answer :)

Comment: Rx is behaving the way I would expect it to here. What is that you actually want to do? It looks like you are trying to use Rx to execute parallel processing (which is not really what it is designed for).

Comment: @Lee, See my comment below your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is by design! As [Microsoft](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2b56aaa2-aa8e-4f09-a2b0-f9a042efa5a4/observeonthreadpool-uses-newthread?forum=rx) explains:

> ...Both the TaskPool and CLR ThreadPool schedulers support
>   long-running operations. The former does so through
>   TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning (which really - in today's
>   implementation of the TPL - amounts to creating a new thread); the
>   latter calls into NewThread to achieve the same effect. What matters
>   more than the specific type of scheduler used is the achieved effect.
>   In this particular case, one expects asynchrony caused by introduction
>   of additional concurrency.

It also goes on to say:

> In case you really want to have a thread pool thread under any
>   circumstance (e.g. to enforce a global maximum degree of parallelism
>   for your app - though keep in mind things like
>   TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning are wildcards to bypass this
>   mechanism), you'll have to apply the ***DisableOptimizations*** extension
>   method to the ThreadPoolScheduler instance to make it fall back to
>   recursive behavior. Notice you can pass in the interfaces you want to
>   disable (specifying none means disabling all optimizations), in this
>   case typeof(ISchedulerLongRunning) suffices.

Comment: In my case I'm still getting the same thread Id :            var collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance.DisableOptimizations(typeof(ISchedulerLongRunning));
            Observable.FromEventPattern<NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(collection, "CollectionChanged", ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
            .Subscribe(x => {
                Console.WriteLine($" {x.EventArgs.NewItems[0]} { Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId }");
                
            }
            ,()=> {  });

            while (true) collection.Add("hello");

Comment: sorry that did not come out very nicely

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment above, It looks like you are trying to use Rx (a library for querying and composing observable sequences of data) as a Parallel computation library?

I think to see the results you were expecting you could hack your query to be like this

```
Console.WriteLine("Main Thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

var source = Observable.Range(1, 10, TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
    .SelectMany(i=>Observable.Start(()=>i, NewThreadScheduler.Default))
    //.ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
    .Subscribe(n =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Value: {0} Thread: {1} IsPool: {2}",
            n, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);
    });
```

output:

```
Main Thread: 11
Value: 1 Thread: 15 IsPool: False
Value: 4 Thread: 21 IsPool: False
Value: 2 Thread: 14 IsPool: False
Value: 3 Thread: 13 IsPool: False
Value: 5 Thread: 21 IsPool: False
Value: 6 Thread: 21 IsPool: False
Value: 7 Thread: 21 IsPool: False
Value: 8 Thread: 21 IsPool: False
Value: 9 Thread: 21 IsPool: False
Value: 10 Thread: 21 IsPool: False
```

Note that we see multiple threads in play here, but also note that we now get out-of-order values (obviously as we are introducing concurrency that we no longer control). So it is a case of picking your poison (or your appropriate lib)

Comment: Thanks for the example, I was not using RX as a parallel library as there are far better alternatives; however I was exploring the behavior of RX with the TPL (specifically it's schedulers) as the reference point. I expected the `Scheduler` to behave just like a scheduler `should` behave (based on their name) which in this case was not due to optimization and thread reuse. The answer above from Microsoft clarified this behavior.

Comment: Well due to the behavior contracts (specifically the serialization ones) that @Enigmativity has outlined, the schedulers are behaving how they *should*. To introduce uncontrolled concurrency would break the fundamentals that Rx is built on. "_The fact that they run sequentially is a mystery_". That is specifically the contract that we want Rx to enforce; sequential callbacks.

Comment: I disagree, I do not see any behavior contracts here instead, I see lots of confusion. I don't know about you but a behavior contract which can be disabled via an extension method named `DisableOptimisations` does not look right to me :-) If that is how RX is meant to behave, fine, however it has introduced a `mysterious complex` behavior which baffled even the most experienced RX developers around me as well as those who attempted to answer this thread but ended up deleting their posts.

Comment: You _can_ break the contracts in alsorts of ways. Most of the operators will try to stop you doing it, but as of V1 they relaxed these in favor of performance (example : `.Synchronise()`). It is still unclear what you are trying to achieve, as Rx is behaving exactly as I would expect. It seems you _want_ it to run you OnNext handler in a reentrant/parallel manner. If that is the case, then Rx is not for you.

Comment: Maybe more constructively, can you post a new question with what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: As explained above, I have the answer to my qeustion.

Answer (score 1):

To start with Rx has a behaviour contract. It will only handle a single value through an observer at one time. If more than one observer is attached to an observable (usually only hot observables) then a single value is run through each observer, one at a time, before the next value is produced.

That explains why your values are produced one after another.

Now secondly, as to why they run on the same thread. That's basically a result of optimizing performance based on the above behaviour contract. It takes time and resources to spin up new threads, so the Rx team try to reuse threads where possible to avoid the overhead.

It should be clear than an observable running on one thread might produce values faster than its observers can process them. If that's the case they queue up. So, for any of the schedulers that spin up new threads to observe on then the logic is this - if the observers finish processing a value then the currently running thread inspects the queue to see if there is another value to process and if there is it processes it - no new thread needed. If there isn't then the thread is ended or returned to the `TaskPool` etc, so when a new value becomes available that thread is gone and an alternative is needed. The `NewThreadScheduler` spins one up. The `TaskPoolScheduler` gets one from the `TaskPool` etc.

So, this boils down to a simple optimization to speed up processing when values are queued up to be processed sequentially.

---

In my tests I couldn't create a single observable sample that uses new threads for each new value when using `NewThreadScheduler`, but then I found this in the `NewThreadScheduler` source:

```
public override IDisposable Schedule<TState>(TState state, TimeSpan dueTime, Func<IScheduler, TState, IDisposable> action)
{
  if (action == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
  EventLoopScheduler eventLoopScheduler = new EventLoopScheduler(this._threadFactory);
  eventLoopScheduler.ExitIfEmpty = true;
  return eventLoopScheduler.Schedule<TState>(state, dueTime, action);
}
```

So, under the hood it is creating a new `EventLoopScheduler` (single non-changing thread scheduler) and handing over the scheduling to this. No wonder the thread doesn't change.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I am still slightly confused here. I thought by putting the `Thread.Sleep` I was simulating a long running execution for each notification therefore circumventing the optimization. I find this optimization behavior for the `NewThreadScheduler` to be counter-intuitive though it would make sense for something like `ThreadPoolScheduler` or `TaskPoolScheduler`. How would you modify the above example to get one thread per invocation?

Comment: @MaYaN - The call to `Thread.Sleep` just pauses the thread so to Rx it is like the observer just took a long time to complete. It simulates work, not a thread yield. The optimization is no different for any of the schedulers so I don't think it counter-intuitive for `NewThreadScheduler`. Now making a sample that does work in the way you expect is being a little tricky. I've tried to create one, but it's sticking to the one thread - I'm trying to figure out why.